# Can i use a PWM HHO Controller to control Brushless DC Motor?

Tags: arduino, pwm, brushless-dc-motor

Hi im a electronics newbie.
The part im talking about is

```
DC 10-50v 12V 24V 48V 3000W 60A amps DC Motor Speed Control PWM HHO Controller
```

[here is the link](http://www.ebay.in/itm/221636836855?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649)

My question is can this type of part be used to control brushless DC motors ?

Edit. Motor Specifications

```
24V, 320W, Brushless
```

Comment: DC motors rated for which voltage? If the voltage is within this controller operating range it should work. Remembering you will need to power it up with the maximum DC motor voltage.

Comment: @GleisonStorto - thanks for the comment. i have edited the question to add motor specifications

Comment: *** NOTE *** The controller that you linked is for controlling the speed of a regular two wire style of DC motor. It is NOT a controller for a brushless DC type motor. A brushless DC motor will have four motor wires (Phase A, B and C + Common) and Hall Sensor connections (three wires plus hall pwr/gnd). It should quite obvious that eBay controller does not support these connections.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot drive a brushless motor, you need a PWM speed controller specifically for brushless (BLDC) motors, while this only states that it drives a "DC Motor".

This is effectively a variable DC supply, where the BLDC controller you need is a variable 3-phase AC supply, whose frequency is tuned to match the motor speed.

Answer (score 0):

Brushless motors and brushed DC motors require different types of controls.  A brushed DC motors can run off of PWM to control the speed.  Brushless motors don't have a commutator and brushes to do the commutation so they require the control to do the commutation.